# Why does my web application automatically gets the nuget package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform added to it?

Tags: asp.net, .net

When I create a new web application (.net 4.6.1) using Visual Studio 2017, I get a nuget package installed (`Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`) and my web.config file contains the following:

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler extension=".cs" language="c#;cs;csharp" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:7.0 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <compiler extension=".vb" language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008,40000,40008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

What is the use of this `codedom` here?

From what I gather so far this is related to the new rosyln compiler.. but I don't see why this is needed here.
If I remove this NuGet package, it removes these lines from the web.config file as well.. But nothing seems to be affected as far as my web application is concerned.

I thought if I check the runtime directory, it might point to the `bin\roslyn`, folder.. but it doesn't it still point to: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\`

So, I am wondering what is the use of this package? and why is this added to my web app by default?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell. It also will depend if you using a asp.net application vs that of a asp.net web site.

For example, while a web site applcation does a FULL compile and creates all the .dlls BEFORE publish to the web site? That means the web site DOES NOT re-compile your code.

However, I been bitten, since app_code DOES get re-compiled. I introduced some vb.net code, and started using the free text ability. (really nice for in-line sql statements).

However, when app_code attempted to re-compile that code (IIS + asp.net web site does), then that code would not compile anymore.

My simple solution? I simple create a new folder called MyCode, and set the properties of each code modules (my global utility routines) to compile.

eg this:

[image]

In other words, I 100% dumped the use of app_code, since while ALL other code is pre-compiled (I'm using a asp.net web site applcation and NOT a asp.net web site).

So, while in most cases you don't care or need Roslyn support, and everything "seems" to work on your local computer during development? Be careful, if you introduce code syntax that depends on some of the Roslyn features, then at deploy time, when the web site attempts to compile the code, it will not have Roslyn.
(its possible that the web server can be updated to support Roslyn, but I don't really know, and I don't want to find out!).

And since you seem to have both c# and vb.net setup? Then this suggests you may well be running a mixed environment, and thus NOT using a web site applcation, but using a web site, and THAT means that IIS and the web site going to do the compiling here, not your local dev machine before deploy.

This then does mean some caution is required, and I would probably suggest you disable use of Roslyn during development.

So, I can't be 100% sure - but it the simple answer is they shoved in a nuget package to help with this issue.